# Cannot connect to localhost using another computer in internet

Tags: apache, localhost

Like in title, I have a problem and I don't know why it doesn't work. Firewall is disabled. Here sreens with my configuration:

```
http://ziggy.vot.pl/configuration/1.jpg
http://ziggy.vot.pl/configuration/2.jpg
http://ziggy.vot.pl/configuration/3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You should forward to 8080 port and not to 80.

Is 89.74.98.57 you public IP? Can you ping them? Try also:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work. Yes this is public ip of my router. Port is set to 8080.

Comment: I mean set port redirecting to 8080. In your 1.jpg in "internal" you forward to port 80, but apache listen on port 8080.